# App Engine Connected Android App Warning: You must run the ValidationTool as part of your server build process

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm getting this warning after creating a new App Engine Connected Android App:

```
Cannot fully validate context since domain type com.foo.server.HelloWorldService is not available.
You must run the ValidationTool as part of your server build process.

Add @SuppressWarnings("requestfactory") to dismiss.
```

As this is in the shared folder, there is a copy in the Android part and one in the App Engine part.  The warning appears ONLY in the Android part over the names of the interface methods here:

```
package com.foo.client;

import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.InstanceRequest;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Request;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestContext;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.RequestFactory;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.ServiceName;

import com.foo.shared.MessageProxy;
import com.foo.shared.RegistrationInfoProxy;

public interface MyRequestFactory extends RequestFactory {

  @ServiceName("com.foo.server.HelloWorldService")
  public interface HelloWorldRequest extends RequestContext {
    /**
     * Retrieve a "Hello, World" message from the server.
     */
    Request<String> getMessage();
  }

  @ServiceName("com.foo.server.RegistrationInfo")
  public interface RegistrationInfoRequest extends RequestContext {
    /**
     * Register a device for C2DM messages.
     */
    InstanceRequest<RegistrationInfoProxy, Void> register();

    /**
     * Unregister a device for C2DM messages.
     */
    InstanceRequest<RegistrationInfoProxy, Void> unregister();
  }

  @ServiceName("com.foo.server.Message")
  public interface MessageRequest extends RequestContext {
    /**
     * Send a message to a device using C2DM.
     */
    InstanceRequest<MessageProxy, String> send();
  }

  HelloWorldRequest helloWorldRequest();

  RegistrationInfoRequest registrationInfoRequest();

  MessageRequest messageRequest();
}
```

I'm using latest (non-beta) versions of all plugins provided by Google on Eclipse Classic 3.7 (as suggested).

What IS the validation tool, how do I run it, and what does this warning mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is new in GWT 2.4.0, see http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation

The ValidationTool will generate a `com.foo.client.MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder` class (or, in the case of the Android client, maybe a `com.foo.client.MyRequestFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilderLite`) that's needed to encode and decode context and proxy types, and methods to/from obfuscated names over the wire.